# Comparing two objects using Apache reflection fails

Tags: android, object, compare

I have two objects that are identical in every way (that I am aware of) - in other words, all properties are identical.

```
Object A

Object B
```

The class implements Apache reflection is as such:

```
public class Base<T> {

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        try {

            if (!this.getClass().isInstance(obj)) {
                return false;
            }

            if(EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(this, obj)){
                return true;
            }

            return false;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }    
}
```

Where `org.apache.commons.lang.builder.EqualsBuilder` is the namespace used.
However, whenever I use this equal method to compare them, it returns false.

The objects are implementations of the following:

```
public class Device extends Base<Object> implements Serializable{


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int _id = -1;
    private long create_date = 0;
    private long update_date = 0;
    private int other_id = -1;
    private String description = "";
    private int configuration_id = -1;
    private long sync_date = 0;
    private Device_Info device_info = null;

    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void set_id(int _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public long getCreate_date() {
        return create_date;
    }

    public void setCreate_date(long create_date) {
        this.create_date = create_date;
    }

    public long getUpdate_date() {
        return update_date;
    }

    public void setUpdate_date(long update_date) {
        this.update_date = update_date;
    }

    public int getOther_id() {
        return other_id;
    }

    public void setOther_id(int other_id) {
        this.other_id = other_id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getConfiguration_id() {
        return configuration_id;
    }

    public void setConfiguration_id(int configuration_id) {
        this.configuration_id = configuration_id;
    }

    public void setSync_date(long sync_date) {
        this.sync_date = sync_date;
    }

    public long getSync_date() {
        return sync_date;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public ContentValues getContentValues() {

        // define an object to contain the object values
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        try {

            // set the values of each table column.
            if(this.get_id() > 0){
                values.put("_id", this.get_id());   
            }                       
            values.put("create_date", this.getCreate_date());
            values.put("update_date", this.getUpdate_date());           
            values.put("description", this.getDescription());                   
            values.put("other_id", this.getOther_id());
            values.put("configuration_id", this.getConfiguration_id());
            values.put("sync_date", this.getSync_date());

            return values;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return values;
        }
    }

    public Device_Info getDevice_info() {
        return device_info;
    }

    public void setDevice_info(Device_Info device_info) {
        this.device_info = device_info;
    }
  }
```

Device info is another class similar to the device class (an extension really), but just has more detailed properties.  As previously mentioned, these two objects are identical - I set each property manually to the same value in each object and verify by checking each property individually.

This method works on more simple objects, but I do not understand why it fails on this more complex object?  By complex I mean a class that has another class as a property.  The Android ContentValues *does not appear* to affect success/fail.